# $\frac{b+\delta(b)}{a+\delta(a)}$ -- Calculus for the Ambitious

Tags: calculus

I am reading book titled "Calculus for the Ambitious" by TW Korner, he had made it available legally for free here:  https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/

In first chapter he is teaching about how small errors affect bigger values.  On page number 7, he has this problem:

$\frac{b+\delta(b)}{a+\delta(a)}$

He says, "if we stare at the problem long enough, the following idea may occur to us:

$u = \frac{1}{a}$  and $u + \delta(u) = \frac{1}{a+\delta(a)}$

and goes onto solving the equations for \delta(u) and then finds this at the end:

$\frac{b+\delta(b)}{a+\delta(a)}$ = $\frac{b}{a} - \frac{b * \delta(a)}{a^2} + \frac{\delta(b)}{a}$

### [image]

[image]

---

I got 2 questions:

1. I can stare long enough, 4 hours, but such ideas don't occur to me.
2. why choose $u = \frac{1}{a}$, I can also use: $u - \delta(u) = a$, and it will simplify the answer to: $\frac{b}{a} - \frac{\delta(b)}{a}$ . Why choose one over the other ?

Comment: You can type it better with https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's so cool to learn MathJax  :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

$\textsf{(1)}$ Long enough can sometimes mean too long to be sensible...but the time gets shorter when you see more problems.

$\textsf{(2)}$ If you use $u=\frac1a$ and try $u+\delta u = a $ then $\delta u = a - \frac1a$ which can be very large, for instance if $a=100$ then $u = 0.01$, but $\delta u = 99.99 $. So the approximation property
$$ u+\delta u \approx u$$
doesn't hold.

Comment: You used numbers (integers) to clarify the problem and I understood it very well.  Now, author himself in the book, did not use any numbers. Should I assume, such kind of error-correction was already done using numbers while he was writing the book or while such error-formulas  are being derived/found, they are always backed by practical proof using numbers.

Comment: @Arnuld I think its correct to think of what he writes as being true for any (reasonable) collection of actual numbers, yes. In this case, the choice could have been motivated by the graph of $1/x$, and a graph is a large collection of such 'practical' numerical evidence.